# ‘l’ is no list of MALDIquant::MassPeaks objects

Tags: r, bioinformatics, maldiquant

I'm following [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MALDIquant/vignettes/MALDIquant-intro.pdf) tutorial about MALDIquant package but i'm getting an error, before executing this line

```
peaks <- binPeaks(peaks, tolerance=0.002)
```

The Error is :

> Error: binPeaks(peaks, tolerance = 0.002) : ‘l’ is no list of MALDIquant::MassPeaks objects!

When i do `class(peaks)` :

```
> class(peaks)
[1] "MassPeaks"
attr(,"package")
[1] "MALDIquant"
```

Answer (score 0):

`binPeaks` just works on list of `MassPeaks` objects. Your `class` output shows that you have just a single `MassPeaks` object.

```
 ## load package
 library("MALDIquant")

 ## create two MassPeaks objects
 p <- list(createMassPeaks(mass=seq(100, 500, 100), intensity=1:5),
           createMassPeaks(mass=c(seq(100.2, 300.2, 100), 395), intensity=1:4))

 binnedPeaks <- binPeaks(p, tolerance=0.002)

 ## but not:
 binPeaks(p[[1]])
 # Error: binPeaks(peaks, tolerance = 0.002) : ‘l’ is no list of MALDIquant::MassPeaks objects!
```

Please look at `?binPeaks` for details or write me an email (I am the maintainer, you will find my mail address at [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MALDIquant/index.html).